# How to remove text between a string and a space using SED

Tags: sed

I have a file with repeating line in it like this;

```
<stack-block name="B" sub-type="SBL" type="ABM_BLOCK" level="2" parent-name="PBTYRD" geo-anchor-latitude="-34.96723069348281" geo-anchor-longitude="150.2157080161554" geo-anchor-orientation="72.35290364141252" z-index-min="1" />
<stack-block name="C" sub-type="SBL" type="ABM_BLOCK" level="2" parent-name="PBTYRD" geo-anchor-latitude="-34.967529872288864" geo-anchor-longitude="150.2145108805486" geo-anchor-orientation="72.35290364141252" z-index-min="1" />
```

...and so on...

I want to remove the **geo-anchor-latitude="-34.96723069348281"** section from the lines of a file including the geo-anchor-latitude phrase up to the second double quote.

I have tried `sed -i 's/geo-anchor-latitude.*"//' filename` with no luck as it strips everything from geo-anchor-latitude to the end of the line.

Any clues out there? Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: the latitude value changes for each row, so I cannot use those numbers in any command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
sed -i 's/geo-anchor-latitude="[^"]*"//' filename
```

Output:

```
<stack-block name="B" sub-type="SBL" type="ABM_BLOCK" level="2" parent-name="PBTYRD"  geo-anchor-longitude="150.2157080161554" geo-anchor-orientation="72.35290364141252" z-index-min="1" />
<stack-block name="C" sub-type="SBL" type="ABM_BLOCK" level="2" parent-name="PBTYRD"  geo-anchor-longitude="150.2145108805486" geo-anchor-orientation="72.35290364141252" z-index-min="1" />
```

The regex `geo-anchor-latitude="[^"]*"` matches the substring such as:

- A literal string `geo-anchor-latitude="`
- Followed by a sequence of any characters **except for** `"`
- Followed by a double quote `"`

Then the matched substring above is removed by the `s` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended regular expressions (-E) with sed to do this.

```
sed -Ei 's/geo-anchor-latitude="[-0-9]+[.][0-9]+"//' filename
```

This regex looks for the latitude attribute, followed by a decimal number with any number of digits.